# YII 2 Get Site URL

Tags: yii2, yii-url-manager

My Application is deployed on localhost/upload.

I am using following code to generate relative URL.

```
 Url::to('@web/my_controller/action'); // it returns /upload/my_controller/action
```

But, I need full URL like this instead: http://localhost/upload/my_controller/action.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should simply use a route :

```
Url::to(['my_controller/action']);
```

And if you want an absolute base url :

```
Url::to(['my_controller/action'], true);
```

Read more :

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to()-detail

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#creating-urls

Comment: Nope, i know that but it only returns my_controller/action

Comment: Finally i figured it out, we just need to pass true after the url eg: `Url:to(['my_controller/action'],true)` it will return http://example.com/my_controller/action.

Answer (score 2):

**Follow urlManager And Request In Yiiframework 2.0 with example**

---

- Yii::$app->basePath ****>>>>****  D:\wamp\www\yiiframework2.0\project\backend

---

- Yii::$app->homeUrl;   ****>>>>****   /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php

---

- Yii::$app->getUrlManager()->createUrl(‘user’)     ****>>>>****   /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php?r=user

---

- Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([‘site/page’, ‘id’ => ‘about’]) ****>>>>****
  /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fpage&id=about

---

- Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([‘site/view’, ‘id’ => 105])      ****>>>>****  /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fview&id=105

---

- Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(”) ****>>>>****
  http://127.0.0.1/yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php?r=

---

- Yii::$app->urlManager->createAbsoluteUrl(‘site/view/index’)   ****>>>>****  http://127.0.0.1/yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php?r=site%2Fview%2Findex

---

- Yii::$app->request->baseUrl   ****>>>>****  /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web

---

- Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl ****>>>>****
  http://127.0.0.1/yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php

---

- Yii::$app->request->url ****>>>>****
  /yiiframework2.0/project/backend/web/index.php