# Get full url of current webpage in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, helper, yii2-urlmanager

How to get the full URl in address bar to my Yii2 Model using **yii\helpers\Url**  ?

I use **$currentUrl = Yii::$app->request->url;** but it return site/submit which is defined already in my UrlManager :

```
'urlManager'   => [
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'enablePrettyUrl'     => true,
    'showScriptName'      => false,
    'rules'               => [
        '/'            => 'site/index',
        'site/submit'  => 'site/submit',
        'admin'        => 'admin/index',
        'admin/login'  => 'admin/login',
        'admin/index'  => 'admin/index',
        'admin/logout' => 'admin/logout',
        '/<url:.+>'    => 'site/index',
        'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',

    ],
],
```

Best regards,

Comment: `// http://www.example.com/images/logo.gif
echo Url::to('@web/images/logo.gif', true); ` Resource: https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl#to()-detail

Comment: Also here is the similar answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27959337/yii-2-get-site-url

Comment: They return only my https://example.com/controller/action !!  if i want the full url https://example.com/controller/action/?campagneID=test&keyword=string ? I made some tests with Yii2 url helpers they return https://example.com/site/submit previously declared in UrlManager.

Comment: i use Yii2 thats not work with Yii::$app->request->createAbsoluteUrl( Yii::$app->request->getBaseUrl() );

Comment: This should work like expected: `Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl` Return `http://www.example.com/site/index?Model%5Bcategory%5D=22`

Comment: Sorry, but the return **https://www.example.com/site/submit**

Comment: I think the problem is in ** 'rules'               => [
        '/'            => 'site/index',
        'site/submit'  => 'site/submit',
        'admin'        => 'admin/index',
        'admin/login'  => 'admin/login',
        'admin/index'  => 'admin/index',
        'admin/logout' => 'admin/logout',
        '/<url:.+>'    => 'site/index',
        'defaultRoute' => 'site/index',

    ],*

Comment: Provide url what you trying to get

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco, thanks, my url is : ** https://www.example.com/?id=CAMP1&key=%7Bkeyword%7D&dev=%7Bdevice%7D ** it's represent a destination url coming from google

Comment: Real example : https://www.example.com/?id=CAMP1&key=meilleure%20offre%20internet&dev=m

Comment: It's solved with hack ==> $current_url = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]; thanks @SergheiLeonenco (y)

Answer (score 2):

```
Yii::$app->request->absoluteUrl
```

[image]

[Plz follow this yii2 document](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-web-request)

Answer (score 1):

Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl(Yii::app()->request->url)